# Why does Prinz have no gender ending, but Prinzessin does?

Tags: etymology, gender

It seems like, perhaps, for trans princes and princesses, one could use die Prinzin and der Prinzess, but I am not certain that is the reason the words “*Prinz*” and “*Prinzessin*” developed as they did.
Does anyone know ?

Comment: What makes you think Prinz is special in this regard? The very same reasoning also applies to Chef, Koch, and to probably all other nouns that don't end in -er.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rests on a wrong assumption.

Comment: Your background could probably be English, so a possible answer could be *For the same reason that there is "Prince" and "Princess"*.

Comment: @RolandIllig: "Er" ist keine männliche Endung. Müller ist keine männliche Form von Müll. Außerdem ist die weibliche Form ja Müllerin und nicht Müllin. Mutter und Butter sind auch nicht männlich oder Mauer und sicher Dutzend andere.

Comment: König, Fürst, Baron, Häuptling aber auch Löffel, Hammer, Stuhl haben auch keine männliche Endung. Nur für Berufe und Funktionen, wenn wir unterstreichen wollen, dass eine Frau sie ausführt, haben wir die ~in-Form. Während die Wörter oft männliches Geschlecht haben (Professor, Bauer) heißt es nichts über die Person. Dazu muss man "männlicher Bauer" etc. sagen, sonst ist das Geschlecht dessen, der Bauer ist, offen. ("Als Bauer verdient man zu wenig.")

Comment: @userunknown "wenn wir unterstreichen wollen", selbst wenn die bezeichnete Person das gar nicht gern hat. Analog zum Bauer ist mir gestern der dritte Koch, weiblich, begegnet, der/die als Hobby Genderpropheten predigt, das Wort 'Köchin'  entweder aus der schieren Existenz zu streichen, aus guten Gründen (es folgte die Predigt) oder sich auf einen Abend mit Hunger einzustellen. Die verdutzten Studentengesichter wurden dann doch noch satt. Aber es bleibt zu kompliziert für einfache Regeln… (Steht der 'Müller' hier irgendwo of deSE zum upvoten?)

Answer (score 3):

Like in English the etymology of both, the German [*Prinz*, and *Prinzessin*](https://dwds.de/wb/Prinz) is from old French *prince* and *princess*. These again are derived from Latin *princeps* (principle).

So the peculiar male and female forms did not develop in German but in French. Interestingly in German there was an interim word *[Prinzesse](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GP07666#XGP07666)* which is closer to the French root. The additional Germanized ending *-in* came later.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you start with the English terms

> prince, princess

(and quite similar in French, which should be deemed the direct source of these words in German, as French was for formative centuries the lingua franca in higher society in Europe)

you get German forms

> Prinz, *Prinzess

Now, German "Prinzess" (for a female such) is very unusual (although not unthinkable<sup>1</sup>); I would say it was just because there is a common practice to add *-in* to titles like this for female forms, the -in was added to *princess*, too, although in French/English the -ess would already be sufficient to indicate feminitiy.

---

<sup>1)</sup> See examples and historical evidence given by commenters below.

Comment: You're right about *Prinzess* not being unthinkable: take *Prinzessbohne*, for example. Also, *Prinzess* sounds like an old-fashioned form, but the diminutive is still formed using it: *Prinzesschen*.

Comment: @Philipp The diminutive is a a very good argument!

Comment: @Christian: it would suffice in Dutch too: *prins*, *prinses*. Just like: *leraar*, *lerares* (teacher), and many others. But we have words ending in *-in* too: *boer*, *boerin* (farmer).

Comment: In der Tat sagt [Pfeifer](https://dwds.de/wb/Prinz#et-1), dass *Prinzeß* bis ins 19. Jh. fortgelebt hat. *Prinzesse* ist älter.

Comment: Comments are temporary only. Please do not refer to comments in your answer, copy and paste them as an [edit] instead.